# C# revit addin Error: Upload failed. Reason = Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

We are using c# revit addin in our project.

Design automation requests are getting failed with the error **"status": "failedUpload",**

Here is the report file for more details

```
[09/08/2022 17:30:21] Finished running.  Process will return: Success
[09/08/2022 17:30:21] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[09/08/2022 17:30:25] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[09/08/2022 17:30:25] End script phase.
[09/08/2022 17:30:25] Start upload phase.
[09/08/2022 17:30:25] Uploading 'T:\Aces\Jobs\ad78879202894efba8c5145367e8275d\result.rvt': verb - 'PUT', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/generatedmodels/objects/20220908164214_1305 - Interior purged.rvt'
[09/08/2022 17:31:27] Error: Retrying on GatewayTimeout. Request is 'PUT' 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/generatedmodels/objects/20220908164214_1305 - Interior purged.rvt'
[09/08/2022 17:32:34] Error: Retrying on GatewayTimeout. Request is 'PUT' 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/generatedmodels/objects/20220908164214_1305 - Interior purged.rvt'
[09/08/2022 17:33:51] Error: Retrying on GatewayTimeout. Request is 'PUT' 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/generatedmodels/objects/20220908164214_1305 - Interior purged.rvt'
[09/08/2022 17:35:23] Error: Retrying on GatewayTimeout. Request is 'PUT' 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/generatedmodels/objects/20220908164214_1305 - Interior purged.rvt'
[09/08/2022 17:35:23] Error: Failed - 504 (GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)
Request: PUT https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/generatedmodels/objects/20220908164214_1305 - Interior purged.rvt
  Request Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlU3c0dGRldUTzlBekNhSzBqZURRM2dQZXBURVdWN2VhIn0.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJidWNrZXQ6ZGVsZXRlIiwiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImRhdGE6Y3JlYXRlIiwiY29kZTphbGwiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoidFBvVGQ0dENuTEhrajlZMEtRYWRyVFdBT0pLSUxzN1AiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvYWp3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiU0pnc1N2TjdKTjhFSkhNeFRpdUhmMko2Y3ZTTXhZVW9UZXphcmRJcFNocHZjOWFDM1pzdVVPeDhESjNRc0toViIsImV4cCI6MTY2MjY1ODc0OH0.PJPp7LroxjWkFD7i3_ErLGyM_wS_D0ir1Qr-w9TfHazaEpmZSrwQ6QsRKcJ9ibXS5z9RY_5WGtzojDPyNTF4kP9TISpgJlyJivbLTnxv7oqW_acd0FvQYlvsaozrx_HIfRJIJLLuF_k1gGwpeArK9yQrKtWYSY1_5c3t1QQSEAs4i5HVyWlPPT8eEsQDtY_EYj32QQoeIMnfI3XWWQBkhD1LnbI9yIzLJ0D8ZWzXbbzD78wAhYudzLsW_0ay3YQRd6fTerUVLHaQ0UgyjvFfTVOV5mFZimERqtpyKynIEnF4JBKZGzhzxv-OlEVNe31o5CLr4oy1QBj_E53q5ZX4Ug
  Request Content Headers:
    Content-Length: 818163712
  Response Headers:
    Connection: keep-alive
  Response Content Headers:
    Content-Length: 0
  Response Body:
    
[09/08/2022 17:35:23] Error: Upload failed. Reason = Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (GATEWAY_TIMEOUT).
[09/08/2022 17:35:23] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
[09/08/2022 17:35:24] Job finished with result FailedUpload
[09/08/2022 17:35:24] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedUpload",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/tPoTd4tCnLHkj9Y0KQadrTWAOJKILs7P/ad78879202894efba8c5145367e8275d/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCgs4MB0vOFtfkJkyouuTSkaG5tzGqnIwaHN41D2ec5IgIgO8%2BddPJXEyQV0NP3R6iKxG7LGccF%2FJtCOZfmDc6oANsqgAMIMBADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDMhdkXkWdvEoT%2BJc%2FSrdAk0REkrcSRlPtnlJTvPShrpoDhptZ%2FsoZAkNW%2BSWnSY%2FZom%2BNsa2qpmWopbOljmbOcBcmhh2K4JG9dN1AbErLjwd73f3cEId3gQoaE7O1CuBNhzl27K7MQ4tCva%2FxdkYNFV6r0Z%2FdJSylvSYrFyrrTS1jK5da2bL6tXBaJ1GByvRiOlGlDrXFyvNSnp%2FTJT1tJhX6wUGgpUaydqSHGfBsqXR%2Bwzskf8iKLZ7Z75oqCkZwmC9azQARwRT0PoSLTcR4RotaqDDdV8xYqCDUE0Us1ihVMYHKW%2FIrgMiDt5Vb3Cx5YJ68SNbNUAPG5JTmTyG%2BlWQiVXaV3IrH4SWktb494A5CJNJo6CkRmusDEPrvnEfiebWxAUwepcJl%2FU%2FJ8jj7Et1oROuReOS9obYtNHlodcEIOuaG62bsgw53awHzz095z9FV9ZNbStdmqb032uJmiSBWfaPr%2F8Zz7oSiykwpZDomAY6ngF5QHnzayjkxc04F41tGu31CD6DyAhmHq6XVZIUa3hwer76cIjHaZFSM1hWlrCwUUfGesfXXVI81KJrqaqyXkUkUshGBD2tEtvvyYb1CnYvnVssn28Rc0LNNl8WgFwPlfrPutbxT5yRsYTD1aAD2B80wHwBJ7vNLNUnonRMWUzY8QW%2BTO9F8pzb%2FGjLqQTlj3Ne4SM4Fpz8EXIng4gmNA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3BTQV7AHO/20220908/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220908T164217Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f60e89e4fbd1527ba46c42480e64268483c15c5efdcb80ed2623144fbd222317",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-09-08T16:42:17.9517893Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-09-08T16:42:18.2481411Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-09-08T16:43:20.1483203Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-09-08T17:30:25.5436836Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2022-09-08T17:35:23.6506512Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1574150920
  },
  "id": "ad78879202894efba8c5145367e8275d"
}
```

Please help me to figure out the solution for this problem?

Comment: The way to upload to OSS is changing and we have updated tutorials on how to do it for Design Automation, have you checked the new update - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/

Comment: I have tried this documentation but it did not work for me. With this code design automation is completing with success but output file in not getting saved in bucket.

Comment: Here is the report file logs
[09/15/2022 11:09:30] Start upload phase.
[09/15/2022 11:09:30] Uploading 'T:\Aces\Jobs\bdd341a5eca142e9889dd00311580278\result.rvt': verb - 'PUT', url - 'https://com-autodesk-oss-direct-upload.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/signed-url-uploads/0af8e5e8-e237-48d6-8702-f631a3d9a8dd?uploadId='
[09/15/2022 11:09:32] End upload phase successfully.
[09/15/2022 11:09:32] Job finished with result Succeeded
[09/15/2022 11:09:32] Job Status:
{
  "status": "success",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-",
  "id": "bdd341a5eca142e9889dd00311580278"
}

Comment: stats for the workitem are: 

"stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2022-09-15T11:07:11.1323252Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2022-09-15T11:07:11.2650655Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2022-09-15T11:07:32.6599924Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2022-09-15T11:09:30.3310184Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2022-09-15T11:09:32.4128105Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1156523861,
    "bytesUploaded": 264925184
  },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to finalize the upload, i.e, after design automation puts file to your s3 bucket you need to call  buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/signeds3upload

This can be done in OnCallback event, refer https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/7d57b39014de5fccb0f082a9dd50a039bdcb2569/forgesample/Controllers/DesignAutomationController.cs#L456

Refer - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/#step-4-complete-the-upload